# How to remove only the last comma in a file using Unix?

Tags: csv, unix, sed, tr

My file `SQL_INPUT.csv` will have the value like below (no. of values won't be necessarily 3; it will amount to even 300, but the format will be like the one below).  I need to only remove the last comma:

```
'YC101692','YE100097','YU102391',
```

I have tried the below

```bash
sed '$ s/,$//' SQL_INPUT.csv
```

but it didn't give any result (didn't remove the last `,`). I also tried:

```bash
SQL_INPUT.csv | tr -d ",$"
```

but it removed all commas.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of this in your post: `head -n 1 SQL_INPUT.csv | hexdump -C`

Comment: `tr` does not use regular expressions at all, it just deals with *sets of characters*

Comment: Will the input consist of one line or many lines?  If it contains many lines, do you need to remove the trailing comma from each line, or only the very last line?  Is the file properly formatted with a trailing newline or is that missing?  Do you have DOS-format lines with CRLF (`'\r\n'`) line terminators?  Given that these questions are being asked 8+ years later, I don't really expect a response, but they are questions that I would have wanted answered before trying to provide an answer to this question.  As already noted, `tr` is not part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempt to use sed seemed almost right. I'd say the following should do the trick:

```
sed s/,$// SQL_INPUT.csv
```

Also, if you think there may be spaces following the last comma you could change the command above to something like this:

```
sed 's/, *$//' SQL_INPUT.csv
```

Comment: i tried the above but didnt get any result. am i doing something wrong

 bash-3.2$ sed s/,$// SQL_INPUT.csv | echo

bash-3.2$

Comment: In case the file has DOS line endings, use `s/,[[:space:]]*$//`

Comment: @user3116123 your comment looks like `sed s/,$// SQL_INPUT.csv | echo`, which will print a blank line because of the `| echo`. So drop that, do only `sed s/,$// SQL_INPUT.csv` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/,$/,x)}1' SQL_INPUT.csv
'YC101692','YE100097','YU102391'
```

Comment: I got the below error

bash-3.2$ awk '{sub(/,$/,x)}1' SQL_INPUT.csv
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: There is no error in the `awk` on my system, and there are no special commando that should make it incompatible.  What OS are you on.

Answer (score 0):

Is file generated in Windows, please try below:

```
dos2unix SQL_INPUT.csv SQL_INPUT.csv
sed '$ s/,$//' SQL_INPUT.csv
```